# (FlywaySqlException in Spring) Password authentication failed for user

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, flyway

I try to connect my Spring-Boot-Application with new ***PostgreSQL USER*** (named : *localX_deletion*), but when i run it, that return me **FlywaySqlException** :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException:
> Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "localX_deletion"

> SQL State  : 28P01 Error Code : 0 Message : FATAL : password authentication failed for user "localX_deletion"

I dont understand because i can connect with this user in command-line : `psql -U localX_deletion -h localhost` and when i specify in *spring.datasource* another account the application run as excepted.

***How i create Database/Role:***

1. `CREATE USER localx_deletion;`
2. `CREATE DATABASE localx_deletion OWNER localx_deletion;`
3. `ALTER USER localx_deletion WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'localx_deletion';`
4. `ALTER DATABASE localx_deletion OWNER TO localx_deletion;`
5. `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE localx_deletion TO localx_deletion;`

***What i have already tried to fix it:***

*For each tasks bellow i have restart postgresql service.*

1. Update password/name *role*.
2. Delete all and re-create all.
3. **Setting in pg_hba.conf *local* and *host* as trust** (that works but i dont like update this file, because the old config work fine with the others roles/databases).
4. Purge, remove and reinstall Postgresql

Someone have an idea for fix it please ?

---

**\du** - List of roles

```
       Role name        |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 localx                 | Create DB                                                  | {}
 localx_standalone      | Create DB                                                  | {}
 localx_standalone_test | Create DB                                                  | {}
 localx_deletion        | Create DB                                                  | {}
 localx_test            | Create DB                                                  | {}
 postgr
```

**\l** - List of databases

```
          Name          |         Owner          | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |         Access privileges         
------------------------+------------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------
 localx                 | postgres               | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                     +
                        |                        |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres            +
                        |                        |          |             |             | localx=CTc/postgres
 localx_standalone      | localx_standalone      | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | 
 localx_standalone_test | localx_standalone_test | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | 
 localx_deletion        | localx_deletion        | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | =Tc/localx_deletion               +
                        |                        |          |             |             | localx_deletion=CTc/localx_deletion
 localx_test            | localx_test            | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | 
 postgres               | postgres               | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | 
 template0              | postgres               | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                      +
                        |                        |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1              | postgres               | UTF8     | fr_FR.UTF-8 | fr_FR.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                      +
                        |                        |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

> Operating System : Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa), Postgresql : 12